# How can I create an incremental build to derive output filenames from input filenames?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I must write a plugin to compile files of a certain type not covered by an existing plugin.

My initial requirements are simply that if the input file is changed or if the output is missing, then the task will *not* be up-to-date. In other words, I want the core "working with files" paradigm to work for me.

My first attempt was to declare both `inputs` and `outputs` to see if the project would work as most would expect.

```
class TestPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply (Project project) {
        project.task('compile') {
            doFirst {
                inputs.files.eachWithIndex { inFilename, idx ->
                    def inFile = project.file(inFilename)
                    def outFilename = outputs.files[idx]
                    def outFile = project.file(outFilename)
                    logger.info "converting ${inFile} to ${outFile}"
                    outFile.append "something"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
apply plugin: TestPlugin
compile {
    inputs.file "test.in"
    outputs.file "test.out"
}
```

And it does. At this point it does all I need except for one thing: I have to define `outputs` in correlation with `inputs`. But defining the outputs is complicated enough to warrant factoring that part of the code into the plugin's task.

My next attempt was to try to get the task to define its `outputs` but it fails because when the "populate outputs" code executes, `inputs` is empty and so no `outputs` are added.

```
class TestPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply (Project project) {
        project.task('compile') {
            inputs.files.each { outputs.files.add(it.replaceFirst(~/\.in$/, '.out')) }
            doFirst {
                inputs.files.eachWithIndex { inFilename, idx ->
                    def inFile = project.file(inFilename)
                    def outFilename = outputs.files[idx]
                    def outFile = project.file(outFilename)
                    logger.info "converting ${inFile} to ${outFile}"
                    outFile.append "something"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
apply plugin: TestPlugin
compile { inputs.file "test.in" }
```

The above fails with a "path may not be null..." error caused by indexing an empty `outputs` list (because `inputs` is empty at the time the task's outer block iterates over `inputs`.

I tried populating `outputs` in Project.afterEvaluate and Project.beforeEvaluate but neither worked. The beforeEvaluate closure never executed. The afterEvaluate closure executed, well, after the project was evaluated which means it executed after the task was set as either up-to-date or out-of-date and so it's not useful for what I need.

I also tried `Project.configure` but that didn't work either.

Then I discovered [lazy configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html) but since it's incubating I think I should avoid it. I'm assuming that the Java and C plugins don't use incubating features and that leaves me wondering how those plugins are accomplishing the equivalent of lazy configuration.

Then I found [Gradle plugin for custom language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33083444/1707353) but it doesn't have an answer. It does, however, have a comment leading me to look at a *lot* of gradle source code. Again, I don't think I should have to reinvent the wheel.

Lastly, if I have to push the decision to compile into `doFirst` and not bother with declaring outputs (and thereby abandon task up-to-datedness), then so be it. I just need to know and move on.

For more context, I'm migrating a build away from `ant`. The two udemy.com classes I took helped me a lot but didn't go far enough to lead me in a confident direction to solve the stated problem. I asked a similar question to one of the instructors and its community to no avail.